# How should I coloring the letters like the game "Lingo"

Tags: c#

I'm  creating the same word-only game of Lingo ([See video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/0-geDIVBESk?t=274)). My issue is that the yellow blocks (in word but out of place) are not correctly displayed. All letters are displayed yellow, but out of place. What should happend that the number of yellow letters are representative from those who are out of order. What I have to get the mistery word:

```
        Label[,] labels = new Label[6, 5]{    {l01, l02, l03, l04, l05} ,
                                              {l06, l07, l08, l09, l10} ,
                                              {l11, l12, l13, l14, l15} ,
                                              {l16, l17, l18, l19, l20} ,
                                              {l21, l22, l23, l24, l25} ,
                                              {l26, l27, l28, l29, l30} ,
        };

        TableLayoutPanel[,] blocks = new TableLayoutPanel[6, 5]{    {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5} ,
                                                                    {v6, v7, v8, v9, v10} ,
                                                                    {v11, v12, v13, v14, v15} ,
                                                                    {v16, v17, v18, v19, v20} ,
                                                                    {v21, v22, v23, v24, v25} ,
                                                                    {v26, v27, v28, v29, v30} ,
        };

        Label[,] l = labels;
        TableLayoutPanel[,] v = blocks;

        public static string first_word File.ReadLines(@"link to text file").Skip(word_number - 1)
        public string[] mistery_word = first_word.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
        public string[] compair_letters = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " "};
        public string[] correct_letters = { " ", " ", " ", " ", " "};
```

When pressing the letters at keyboard, the labels in the square are changing. Hitting enter will check:

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        if (l[current_line, a].Text == mistery_word[a]) // So the same = correct
        {
             compair_letters[a] = "0";
             correct_letters[a] = l[current_line, a].Text;
        }
    }

    for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
   {
      if (mistery_word.Contains(l[current_line, a].Text))
      {
          compair_letters[a] = "1";
      }
     } 

for (c = 0; c < 5; c++)
                    {
                        switch (compair_letters[c])
                        {
                            case "0":
                                Correct here
                            case "1":
                                Half here;
                            case "2":
                                Wrong here
                            default:
                                Wrong
                        }
                    }
```

[image: Result untill now]

Also I'm looping 3x (3rth is coloring). Is there a smarter way?

Comment: In the second loop (near: `compair_letters[a] = "1";`) you should also check if that letter was given on the correct place.  It only should get "1" if there are more letters like that which are not at the correct place.  In "SMEEEE" then 2nd,thrd and 4th letter are wrong because the 5th is at the correct place, and there's only 1 "E" in the mistery_word.

Comment: So a compair_letters[a] != "0" behind could help?

Comment: see answer below....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop something like (untested!):

```
for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    String current_letter = l[current_line, a].Text;
    String correctLetters = ""
    for (b=0; b<5; b++) { if (b!=a) { correctLetters += correct_letters[b]; }}
    if (mistery_word.Contains(current_letter) && !correctLetters.Contains(current_letter) )
    {
        compair_letters[a] = "1";
    }
}
```

After thinking a bit more about this, I created next thing:

```
public static string[] check_word_for_lingo(string guess, string secret_word)
{
    String[] checks = new string[5];
    char[] remainingLettersToCheck = secret_word.ToCharArray();
    char[] secretWordLetters = secret_word.ToCharArray();

    for (int a=0; a<5; a++)
    {
        if (guess[a]==secret_word[a])
        {
            checks[a] = "0"; remainingLettersToCheck[a] = ' ';
        } else {
            checks[a] = " ";
        }
    }
    secret_word = new string(remainingLettersToCheck);

    for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        if (remainingLettersToCheck[a] != ' ')
        {
            if (guess[a] != ' ' && secret_word.Contains(guess[a]))
            {
                checks[a] = "1"; remainingLettersToCheck[a] = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                checks[a] = "2";
            }
        }
    }

    return checks;
}
```

it's used like this:

```
String[] checks = new string[5];

string guess = "SOEEE";
string secret_word = "SMORE";
checks = check_word_for_lingo(guess, secret_word);

Console.WriteLine(guess);
Console.WriteLine(secret_word);
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in checks)
{
    Console.Write(item);
    i++;
}
```

Which will output:
SOEEE
SMORE
01220

Testing with the word 'SOEOE' will still return a wrong answer (01210)

Comment: Intresting! I'm gonna have a look what to deal. Thanks. But I know I have to check extra if the letter was already guessed correct

Comment: But if the "o' is once in the word and not guessed right, then 2x1 is not possible